# Как сохранить изображение при помощи NSSavePanel? OSX

Tags: objective-c, swift, macos

Как можно сохранить изображение в выбранную пользователем папку на компьютере с использованием NSSavePanel? Или есть другие способы? Подскажите, пожалуйста, не могу найти инфу на эту тему.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
let savePanel = NSSavePanel()
savePanel.canCreateDirectories = true
savePanel.showsTagField = false
savePanel.nameFieldStringValue = "screenshot.png"
savePanel.level = Int(CGWindowLevelForKey(.modalPanelWindow))
savePanel.begin { (result) in
    if result == NSFileHandlingPanelOKButton {
        guard let url = savePanel.url else { return }

        let bitmapRep = NSBitmapImageRep(cgImage: self.ikimageView.image().takeUnretainedValue())
        let data = bitmapRep.representation(using: .PNG, properties: [:])
        do {
            try data?.write(to: url, options: .atomicWrite)
        } catch {
            print(error.localizedDescription)
        }
    }
}
```

https://gist.github.com/KrisYu/abf3d03a76b781ffc2a26848d713b11e